# child of child movie clip are null in imported object from flex to flash right after being created

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have an Movie Clip in Flash that have subobject of button type which has subobject of input text and movie clips. Right after creation core Moveclip all subobject are set to null, when I expect them to be valid objects.

```
// hierarchy:

// core:MC_Core_design
    // button_1:B_Mybutton
        // text_name   // dynamic text with instance name
        // mc_icon     // movie clip with instance name

var core:MC_Core_design = new MC_Core_design();
addChild(core);
core.button_1.text_name.text = "hello world"; // error: text_name is null
core.button_1.mc_icon.visible = false; // error: mc_icon is null
```

MC_Core_design was created in Flash and exported to Actionscript. I've done this for button_1 class aswell. The code was written using Flex.

When I comment out both lines that result in error I get correct view of the core Movie clip with all subobject.

How can I set subobject properties right after object creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for the Event.INIT from the class when it is created. (If you are not embedding a symbol using the Embed metatag then Flash takes a few milliseconds to initialize the loaded movieclip). This does not seem to be a problem if the Flash IDE swf/swc does not contain any actionscript)

The issue is sometimes it can be really quick, so it fires the INIT event before you get a chance to attach the event listener to the object. so you can't just attach it after you instantiate the object.

A work around is to embed the swf as a byte array, then use the loader class to load the embedded bytes (This lets you set the event listener before calling load).

e.g.

```
[Embed(source="assets.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var assetBytes:Class;

private var clip:MovieClip;
private var loader:Loader;

public function LoadBytesExample()
{
    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onAssetLoaded);
    loader.loadBytes(new assetBytes());
}

 private function onAssetLoaded(e:Event):void
 {
     var loader:Loader = (e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo).loader;
     (e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo).removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onAssetLoaded);

      clip = loader.content as MovieClip;
      this.addChild(clip);

      clip.someTextField.text = "HELLO WORLD";
   }
```

Sorry for the formatting, just wrote that off the top of my head

And the syntax for embedding the symbol (You won't need to load this via a loader as the actionscript in the external swf/swc is stripped).

```
[Embed(source="assets.swf", symbol="somesymbol")]
private var assetSymbol:Class;

private var clip:MovieClip;

public function LoadSymbolExample()
{
   clip = new assetSymbol();
   clip.sometext.text = "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Are there any alternatives? I do not want to change the way I handle resources - they all reside in single flash .swf/swc file

Comment: You can use the [Embed(source='assets.swf', symbol='somesymbol')] to pull the exact resource you want. This does have the benefit of not needing to load via the loader as Flex strips the actionscript from the loaded symbol for you so you dont have to wait for the INIT event.

Comment: Of course those are symbols you have "Exported for actionscript" in the IDE. I like this approach better than just adding a swc to the Flex project libraries. The way you create resources in a single .swf or .swc. Just the syntax of creating the asset

Comment: Digging depeer I found the http://www.comanswer.com/question/flex-actual-creationcomplete-event - how can I set the creationPolicy setting if I choose to stick to SWC solution? I don't want to change everything related to assets in project just because of some setting that can be (hopefully) fixed :)

Comment: Edited the original post to add the syntax for symbol embedding, you don't need to wait for the INIT event if you use this approach

Comment: ... or, if I am wrong, how else I can fix this without changing the way assets are handled? :)

Comment: Well if you use the symbol approach you wont have to change anything except add the Embed tag where needed? (var core:MC_Core_design = new MC_Core_design(); becomes var core:MovieClip = new MC_Core_design();) Remove the swc from the flex library if you added it there. You can listen for the Event.COMPLETE after you declare you variable i.e. after var core:MC_Core_design = new MC_Core_design(); add core.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onInit); but as I pointed out, on very fast machines it is possible for the event to fire before the listener is attached (Possible... not Probable!)

Comment: I get TypeError: Error #1034, cannot convert "MC_Core_MC_Core_design@47eb089" to "MovieClip"

Comment: Sorry you don't have to convert the class to movieclip (Sometimes its a MovieClipLoaderAsset, sometimes a SpriteAsset depending on how you set up to export in the .fla).

Comment: How to set up export in .fla to get MovieClipLoaderAsset?

Comment: It should be by default (It's the Base Class option when exporting for actionscript)... so it should be flash.display.MovieClip though you can change this to flash.display.Sprite (Which makes sense if you don't need the timeline.) Flex then works out if it was a MovieClip or a Sprite and converts to either the MovieClipLoaderAsset or the SpriteAsset.

Answer (score 0):

If I see it right, `button_1:B_Mybutton` is not yet initialized.

I mean something like : `button_1:B_Mybutton = new B_Mybutton();`

About the other two variables **text_name** & **mc_icon** as you describe if they have been initialized already (as you term them as instance names), Iguess they should not give you any problem.

Also I asssume that you are setting access modifiers to all as public.

If you still have problem... pls share how all the required variables are defined. Just the relevant part would be enough.

Comment: Searching through Stackoverflow. I found my problem is very similiar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517475/textfield-instance-inside-a-button-created-in-a-separate-layer-in-flash-is-null-i, but I do not understand the answer presented there - how can I handle event "creationComplete"? I searched through Google but I do not found anything of use